# How to run an existing Argo Workflow after completion of another Argo workflow?

Tags: workflow, webhooks, argo, argo-events, exit-handler

So I have a Argo workflow_B that needs to run after completion of Argo workflow_A which is used by another team. Both workflows already exist I just want to chain them together.
How can I achieve that?

Is it possible to do such thing using exit-handler?
or should I use event-source like Webhook or AWS SNS to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the workflow of workflows pattern?
If team A is able to create workflow on team b namespace

https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/workflow-of-workflows.yaml